# How to fix "Expressions referencing the outer query..." error in Spark-SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an SQL query with a subquery running on Spark. I get this error: "Expressions referencing the outer query are not supported outside of `WHERE/HAVING clauses`". Can you help me to find out the reason?

```
  select distinct NAME from table1, table2 t
  where t.ID = (select min(t.ID) from table1 a where a.WID = table1.WID) and 
 t.WID = table1.WID  and 
 t.VID = table1.VID
```

the error message is as follows:

> "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Expressions referencing the outer query are not supported outside of WHERE/HAVING clauses:
>   Aggregate [min(outer(FAILURE_ID#3104)) AS min(outer())#3404]"

Comment: This doesn't make sense `(select min(t.ID) from table1 a where a.WID = table1.WID)`.  The minimum value from the *outer* table is always going to match.  Hence, you are not doing any filtering.  I assume you intend:  `where t.ID = (select min(a.ID) from table1 a where a.WID = table1.WID)`.

Comment: this code runs on Oracle correctly, I need to translate it into Spark-SQL

Comment: . . I'm not saying it doesn't run.  I'm saying it doesn't do anything sensible because it is only filtering out `t.ID` values that are not `NULL`.  That doesn't seem either particularly useful or the intent of the query..

Comment: ahh okay, you are right, but the point is that I take a small piece of code out of very complex one. Inside the complex one it will make sense. Removing them doesn't solve it. Spark has no outer query referencing and I am looking for a solution.

Comment: . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  I have not only answered the question, but I have fixed it as well.  You might want to consider accepting the answer.  Whether you do or do not, you should ask a *new* question with more appropriate code and examples.

Comment: Do not worry, as soon as I fix it in my db, I will accept your answer. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax!

You can write your query with all table references in the `FROM` clause:

```
select distinct NAME
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.WID = t1.WID  and 
        t2.VID = t1.VID join
     (select tt1.WID, min(tt1.id) as min_id
      from table1 tt1
      group by tt1.WID
     ) tt1
     on tt1.WID = t1.WID and tt1.min_id = t1.id;
```

Or use window functions:

```
select distinct NAME
from table2 t2 join
     (select t1.*,
             min(t1.id) over (partition by t1.WID) as min_id
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 
     on t2.WID = t1.WID  and 
        t2.VID = t1.VID and
        t1.min_id = t1.id;
```

EDIT:

The above assumes a reasonable interpretation of your query.  To mimic the logic as written, you can do:

```
select distinct NAME
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.WID = t1.WID  and 
        t2.VID = t1.VID 
where t1.ID is not null;
```

That is all the subquery is doing.

Comment: ups, your smart solution failed: "cannot resolve '`tt1.id`' given input columns:", I am happy that you are able to use: "proper, explicit, standard JOIN syntax!"

Comment: @NasimiEldarov . . . The column references look correct according to the references in your question.